# Is it possible for a lambda function to create a CloudWatch scheduled event that could be used to trigger another lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch-events

More fundamentally, I'm wondering if there is a reasonable or preferred way to use a lambda function to schedule the execution of another lambda function at a later time.

Comment: you would still have to schedule a lambda function using a cloudwatch event to invoke a lambda function...so you should just use a cloudwatch event (cron)

Comment: @LostJon Yeah, so I understand the workflow of creating a cloudwatch event, providing it a schedule, and passing it a lambda function as a target. However, my question was more so, can I have a separate lambda function initially create this cloudwatch event? This initial lambda function would not require a cloudwatch event trigger of its own.

Comment: yea...sure you can. for JS you would https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudWatchEvents.html#putRule-property. so...each language will have a PutRule API integration then you need to put targets that reference that rule https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudWatchEvents.html#putTargets-property

Comment: @LostJon Amazing! This is exactly what I am looking for, thanks a ton!

Comment: Not sure why you would want to use a Lambda to create the cloudwatch rule. If you want to automate stuff, using Terraform might be a better idea. Here's a good tutorial for the same thing https://medium.com/geekculture/terraform-setup-for-scheduled-lambda-functions-f01931040007 @SnowCart541